# Checkstyle - Exclude folder

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I want to ignore a specific folder (named generated-sources) from my checkstyle reports, because they are generated.

I'm using eclipse-cs for displaying my violations.

i added a suppressionfilter to my xml:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value=".\suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

my suppressions.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="\*generated-sources\*\*\.\*" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
</suppressions>
```

but it is not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<suppress files="[\\/]generated-sources[\\/]" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
```

this works :)

Comment: The trick is that Checkstyle applies the regex to the *file path*, not the binary class name or something. You could shorten the `checks` attribute to `checks="."`.

Comment: Yeah way more detail needed. IE what file. Where

Comment: @StarWind as stated in my question, the file is the suppressions.xml. the path to that file is defined in the checkstyles.xml.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained how it works and why it solves the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the answer from Philipp, I had to use an absolute pathname ( :-( ) for the suppression file:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="/Users/xxx/workspace/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Looks like the Checkstyle plugin is not using the project home directory.

(at least under eclipse luna / Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by *Thomas Welsch* in his answer, there appears to be a problem with using relative pathname for the suppression xml file.

For gradle builds, [This gist](https://gist.github.com/soucekv/a962f788ceb70e418e2f) suggests a workaround:

in `build.gradle`:

```
checkstyle {
    // use one common config file for all subprojects
    configFile = project(':').file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    configProperties = [ "suppressionFile" : project(':').file('config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml')]
 }
```

in `checkstyle.xml`:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${suppressionFile}" default="suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

(the default value allows IDE plugins, that do not have the gradle variable sorted out, to work correctly)

Answer (score 1):

For me using `SuppressionFilter` didn't worked at all. But this works, exactly for the purpose of excluding folder from scanning

```html
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
  <property name="fileNamePattern"  value=".*[\\/]folder-name-here[\\/].*$"/>
</module>
```

Needs to be inserted inside `<module name="Checker">` section.

Docs https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filefilters.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer tries to fill in missing details in the previous answers.

Suppose I have the following maven project, which only lists the directories inside the project.

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── edu
    │   │       └── utexas
    │   │           └── cs
    │   │               ├── liveoak
    │   │               │   ├── common
    │   │               │   ├── tree
    │   │               │   └── zero
    │   │               ├── logging
    │   │               └── sam
    │   │                   ├── core
    │   │                   │   └── instructions
    │   │                   ├── io
    │   │                   ├── ui
    │   │                   │   └── components
    │   │                   └── utils
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── sam-checks.xml
    │       └── sam-suppressions.xml
    └── test
```

`sam-checks.xml` is the checkstyle configuration file and `sam-suppressions.xml` is the [suppression xml document](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter). Inside `sam-checks.xml`, I have

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="src/main/resources/sam-suppressions.xml"/>
    <property name="optional" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Note the location of `sam-suppressions.xml` is relative to the `pom.xml` of the project.

I want to suppress the checks for all the java files under `sam` directory (`main/java/edu/utexas/cs/sam`). To do so, my `sam-suppressions.xml` looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
              files="[\\/]sam[\\/]"/>
</suppressions>
```

I verify my setup with `mvn checkstyle:check`. Everything should work.