# How to use checkstyle:check in a multi module project

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I'm trying to use Maven Checkstyle plugin in a multi module project.
The default setting for `<sourceDirectories>` (where the plugin to start looking for code) is `${project.compileSourceRoots}`. This resolves to `[C:\workspace\projectname\src\main\java]` in my case, i.e. a `List<String>`.

Now, that default path is of no value to me, since my code resides in different places, like so: `[C:\workspaces\projectname\module1\src\main\java]`. Hence, I need to change `<sourceDirectories>` to a list of directories where my code actually is.

So far, so good...

The problem is that `<sourceDirectories>` expects a `List<String>`. I tried the following:

```
<sourceDirectories>
    <sourceDirectory>pathToCode1</sourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>pathToCode2</sourceDirectory>
</sourceDirectories>
```

... but that didn't work. It will take the default path. *(Moreover, `<sourceDirectory>` is deprecated!)*

Having only *one* `<sourceDirectory>` (without the surrounding `<sourceDirectories>`) does work, but `<sourceDirectory>` only takes one path and you can't have more than one `<sourceDirectory>`. So, no cigar. Also, keep in mind `<sourceDirectory>` is deprecated.

I also tried various other methods of providing a `List<String>` to `<sourceDirectories>`, but alas, no progress. Here are some examples:

```
<sourceDirectories>[pathToCode]</sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectories>pathToCode</sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectories>{pathToCode}</sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectories>{[pathToCode]}</sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectories>{{pathToCode}}</sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectories>{{{pathToCode}}}</sourceDirectories>
```

Is there another way of (directly, without "sub-tags") providing a `List<String>` to maven?

Is the plugin broken?

Have I missed something?

**Edits below**

*My project structure:*

```
MyProject
|-- pom.xml <-- plugin runs fine here
|-- domain-module
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       `-- com/example/hello...
|   |           |-- TheCode.java
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           |-- checkstyle.xml
|   |           `-- LICENSE.TXT
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- poms
|   |-- parent
|   |   `-- pom.xml <-- this is my parent pom
```

*My parent pom*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.example.hello</groupId>
                        <artifactId>domain-module</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>domain-module/src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                            <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                            <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                            <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <...>
        </build>
    </pluginManagement>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply drop `sourceDirectories` and run the analysis on the parent pom? By default, it looks for all Java classes. Take a look at [this example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have read that example and I've tried it. unfortunately it does not work. In fact, Checkstyle won't even start when running the plugin from the parent pom. Maybe it is because my project is not structured like that. Please see my updated question for the parent pom configuration I was using.

Comment: This is definitely due to your project not following the Maven conventions. IMO, you would save yourself a LOT of trouble by following it! Try with `<sourceDirectories>` being `../../**/*.java` (or something like that) so that it starts at the root of your project

Comment: That's the problem. `../../**/*` doesn't work because the plugin expects a `List<String>`, not a `String`.

Comment: Furthermore I'm not sure what you mean by "Maven conventions". Would you care to elaborate on that? The example I gave was only a very small part of a big project.

Comment: The Maven convention is that there is a correlation between parent pom / modules and folder structure. Take a look at [this example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#fig-running-aro-dir-struct). Basically, parent POM is a the top of the directory structure and each module is located in a subfolder.

Comment: I'm not convinced that there actually exists a specific convention, per se. I think it heavily depends on the system architecture. I have my parent separated because I need scalability across projects and artifacts. The parent pom primarily contains shared information such as dependency management and properties. However, this is off topic as I fail to see how having my parent in a separate location affects successful execution of the checkstyle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.13 the use of sourceDirectories is broken (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-260).

With 2.12 it works. Andreas Dangel mentioned in Jira:

> The configuration described here
>   [Checkstyle - Exclude folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013322/checkstyle-exclude-folder)
>   still works. Then the exclusion happens in checkstyle, rather than in
>   maven-checkstyle-plugin.