# how to exclude a folder from checkstyle of Gradle on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, checkstyle

I am new for IntelliJ and Gradle, but I have enough experience on Java and Eclipse. I generated some java classes from wsdl file. I put them under `src/main/resources` with a folder name - "generatedsources".

I try to prevent checkstyle for this folder and its subfolders like `src/main/resources/generatedsources/*` with gradle on IntelliJ.

I tried some lines such;

```
task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
        source 'src'
    //    include '**/*.java'
    //    exclude '**/gen/**'
    //    exclude '**/R.java'
    //    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude 'src/main/resources/generatedsources/**'
    }
```

But I'm failed again.

build.gradle;

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'    

...

buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    source 'src'
//    include '**/*.java'
//    exclude '**/gen/**'
//    exclude '**/R.java'
//    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude 'src/main/resources/generatedsources/**'
}
```

---

**EDIT - After recommendations(but still failed!):**

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

description = """BLABLABLA_application"""

war.archiveName = "BLABLABLA.war"

configurations{
    deployerJars
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version: '1.9.3'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.3'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.8'
    compile 'org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring:jaxws-spring:1.9'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.0.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'BLABLABLA', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'repos'
        }
    }
}


buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

wsdl2java{
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ["$projectDir/src/main/resources/BLABLABLA.wsdl"]
    ]
    generatedWsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/gen/java")
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources")
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "2.5.1"
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    exclude '**/your/generated/package/goes/here**'
}

checkstyleMain.exclude '**/your/generated/package/goes/here**'
```

"exclude" in tasks.withType and "checkstyleMain" causes an error such as "cannot resolve symbol"!

Comment: Do you launch checkstyle from Intellij or from Gradle?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov how do I know this? I don't see any code about checkstyle on build.gradle except I wrote code to exclude some folders to prevent checkstyle.

Comment: How do you launch your tests?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I just build the code via Gradle.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I see on build.gradle "apply plugin: checkstyle". It is obvious that answer of your question is "Gradle" :) but how can I exclude these folder from this checkstyle?

Answer (score 17):

When `checkstyle` plugin is applied custom tasks are delivered along with it (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html)), so instead of adding custom task with type `Checkstyle` configure the shipped one. This is how it should be done:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    exclude '**/your/generated/package/goes/here**'
}
```

You can also configure a particular task, not all:

```
checkstyleMain.exclude '**/your/generated/package/goes/here**'
```

Also this is not good practice to put generated sources under `src/main/resources`. Typically such files goes to e.g. `src/gen/java`

Comment: Into which file should I put them? build.gradle? If it is, for your first recommendation, "exclude" gives an error such as "cannot resolve symbol". For your second recommendation, "checkstyleMain" is also gives the same error.

Comment: Yes, in `build.gradle`, in the same file you have `checkstyle` plugin applied. Can you share the whole `build.gradle` file with changes that cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've just copied your `build.gradle` and it works on my workstation. What gradle version are you using?

Comment: version of Gradle is 2.4

Comment: Hm.. It works with gradle 2.4 as well. The problem has to lie elsewhere.

Comment: I gave up trying to solve it with build.gradle. I did it by writing something on checkstyle.xml. I applied the recommendation told in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013322/checkstyle-exclude-folder

Comment: The pattern is an Ant style pattern, so "\*\*/\*.java" for example. The base folder appears to be the source set, so you need "com/example/package/*.java", not something like "\*\*/build/generated-src/\*\*/\*.java". it doesn't appear to be possible to exclude generates sources in that way using this method.

Answer (score 7):

I followed some comments and make it work add this in file `build.gradle`

```
checkstyle {
    config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile("${project.projectDir}/checkstyle-8.34_google_checks.xml")
    toolVersion = '8.34'
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
}

checkstyleMain
    .exclude('com/examples/gen/api/*.java')
    .exclude('com/examples/gen/model/*.java')
    .exclude('com/examples/gen/auth/*.java')
```

Comment: this has worked for me. I tried putting an absolute path to the files to exclude at first, but this has led me to the correct solution of starting to exclude from the base package name. to simplify, I ended up writing `checkstyleMain.exclude '**/generated/**'`

Answer (score 5):

You can only exclude a folder that is in the source set. That is something that had not been mentioned and it caused me to struggle since I am using Intellij. The generated files are in the **build/** folder which is on the same level as **src/**. I tried excluding the build folder for a while but there was no effect. The only solution was to specify the source folder. Since the build folder is not under src (the source folder), it worked immediately.

```
checkstyleMain.source = "src/main/java"
```

I found the solution here: [Specify excludes to Checkstyle task](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/specify-excludes-to-checkstyle-task/5542/2)

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of issues with checkStyle & pmd + QueryDSL
A final solution for me was not to exclude generated sources, but clean them after assemble task: no sources - nothing to analyze! :)

assemble {
    finalizedBy cleanQuerydslSourcesDir
}

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to modify the "checkstyleMain" Task

kotlin dsl use

```
tasks.named<Checkstyle>("checkstyleMain") {
  source("src")
  include("**/*.java")
  exclude("**/com/generated/*.java")
}
```

groovy dsl use

```
tasks.named("checkstyleMain", Checkstyle) {
  exclude("**/com/generated/*.java")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For kotlin dsl use

```
tasks.withType<Checkstyle>() {
    exclude("**/com/generated/*.java")
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. had to add `source = fileTree("${rootDir}/src").apply {
        exclude("$buildDir/generate-resources/main/**")
    }`