# How to prevent gradle checkstyle of monitoring the build folder

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, checkstyle

i have an avro generated tool that create some jave class, thier in turn ships to the build folder.

the problem is that their structure not match with my checkstyle rukes so i want to ignore them
the files under:

```
 C:\src\temp\myproj\build\generated-main-avro-java\
```

my gradle checkstyle configuration is:

```
task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
source 'src'
//    include '**/*.java'
//    exclude '**/gen/**'
//    exclude '**/R.java'
//    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
exclude 'src/main/avro/**'
exclude 'build/**/'
```

}

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
reports {
    xml.enabled false
    html.enabled true
    html.stylesheet resources.text.fromFile('/config/checkstyle/checkstyle-custom.xsl')
}
```

but i still get:

```
[ant:checkstyle] [WARN] C:\src\temp\myproj\build\generated-main-avro-java\.....
```

can you assist of how can i exclude this folder?

(in this example i tried to exclude all the build folder)

can u assist?

Comment: You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994778/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-checkstyle-of-gradle-on-intellij)

Comment: i've started from something similar. i don't have build error - but checkstyle error