# How to exclude a module for checkstyle in a multi-module project

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I have a [multi-module composite build project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

The project structure is this:

```
Panda. // Root project
  -PandaService. // Service module
  -PandaDataAccessLayer // DAL module whose code are generated with JOOQ
```

I want to exclude `PandaDataAccessLayer` module for [checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/), because its code are generated automatically with JOOQ.

My checkstyle.xml is located at `Panda/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml`, and here is the `build.gradle` in my root project `Panda`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    checkstyle {
        toolVersion = '10.7.0'
        configFile =  rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
        checkstyleMain.exclude '**/PandaDataAccessLayer/**'
    }
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    targetCompatibility = '11'
}
```

I can see that checkstyle is running with `./gradlew  build`. However, the generated report still shows that it checks code in `PandaDataAccessLayer` module.

> `Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at:file:///****/panda/PandaDataAccessLayer/build/reports/checkstyle/main.html`

How can I exclude the `PandaDataAccessLayer` completely from checkstyle?

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18013373/2442831

Comment: @Lino : thanks, able to get it work with  https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter, based on the link you posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkstyle - Exclude folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013322/checkstyle-exclude-folder)

Answer (score 2):

To activate checkstyle in the rootProject/main project and all the sub modules then you have to do the following steps

1. In the root project add

```
    allprojects {
        apply plugin: 'java'
        checkstyle {
            toolVersion = '10.6.0'
            configFile = file("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle_google_customized.xml")
            ignoreFailures = false
            maxWarnings = 0
        }
    
        checkstyleMain {
            source = 'src/main/java'
        }
        checkstyleTest {
            source = 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
```

2. In a submodule's gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '10.6.0'
    configFile = file("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle_google_customized.xml")
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
}
```

If you exclude a submodule then only exclude step two and it will only consider the main project